# enviar link com javascript ao selecionar checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Galera tenho um checkbox, e preciso que o javascript envie o link de acordo com o checkbox selecionado.

Exemplo

html:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='1'>
<input type='checkbox' id='2'>
<input type='checkbox' id='3'>
```

Javascript

Bom o javascrip tem que chamar o seguinte link

```
http://link do site/index.php?id=(id igual ao do checkbox)
```

Alguém sabe como fazer isso com javascript?

Comment: Quando queres que o link seja enviado e para onde? Quando o utilizador selecionar o checkbox? Podes explicar melhor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode capturar o valor do elemento selecionado navegando pela árvore DOM.

```js
var elementA = document.getElementById("a");
var elementB = document.getElementById("b");
var elementC = document.getElementById("c");

var urlComplement = "id=";

elementA.addEventListener("click", display);
elementB.addEventListener("click", display);
elementC.addEventListener("click", display);

function display(){
    if(this.checked){
 alert(urlComplement + this.value);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="a" value=1>
<input type="checkbox" id="b" value=2>
<input type="checkbox" id="c" value=3>
```

Existem várias alternativas melhores do que a postada no exemplo, recomendo fortemente a leitura http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp, procure também sobre manipulação de árvore DOM via Javascript irá auxiliar altamente nos projetos.

Comment: ok muito obrigado

Comment: ok muito obrigado, porém quanto mais input eu colocar mais tenho que adicionar no javascript, tem alguma forma de fazer isso automático, ou seja sem necessidade de adicionar mais linhas no javascript?

Comment: Existe sim, você pode procurar por um elemento pai e navegar por todos os elementos filhos adicionando o eventListener que você deseja. Fazer isso direto pela árvore DOM é um pouco trabalhoso, o JQuery consegue resolver isso de uma forma muito mais simples que a manipulação direta do DOM.

Comment: @HugoBorges Na verdade é bem fácil fazer isso, e.g. atribua aos `input`s a mesma class e então adicione os event handlers em todos eles ao mesmo tempo com `document.getElementsByClassName('eventCheckbox').addEventListener("click", display);`. Se precisar de algum seletor mais complexo use `document.querySelector`.